How to fix error: Private key not found pkcs11-tool
after install pkcs11-tools, here are my steps:
$ alias p11tool='pkcs11-tool --module /usr/local/lib/libpkcs11-proxy.so'
$p11tool --list-slots
$p11tool --keypairgen --key-type RSA:2048 --label "My Key" --token-label "Test Token" --login --pin 1234
$ p11tool --list-objects --token-label "Test Token" --login --pin 1234
$echo "Hello World!" > message.txt
$ p11tool --sign --id 1 --mechanism SHA256-RSA-PKCS \
     --token-label "Test Token" --pin 1234 \
     --input-file message.txt \
     --output-file message.txt.sig

and I got the error
``error: Private key not found
Aborting.```
